# Problems with changing labels with facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am really struggling with something that should be simple, to change the labels in my facet_grid plot, but it doesn't work. This is a plot of kills of one animal species as a function of the number of tourists in an area in three periods:

[image]

I need to change the labels "1", "2", and "3" to the right in the plot, and thought this script should do it:

```
library(ggplot2)
new_labels <- c("1" = "cat.1", "2" = "cat.2", "3" = "cat.3")
ggplot(pe_ki, aes(people,kills)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_grid(class~category, labeller = labeller(category = new_labels)) +
  facet_grid(rows=vars(period)) +
  stat_smooth(method="glm", method.args = list(family = "poisson"),col="black") +
  theme(strip.background = element_rect(fill="lightblue", size=1, color="darkblue"))
```

The data:

```
dput(pe_ki)
structure(list(period = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), month = c("JAN", 
"FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", 
"NOV", "DEC", "JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", 
"AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC", "JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", 
"MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"), people = c(4068L, 
7251L, 14384L, 20513L, 18748L, 17760L, 23433L, 22878L, 12815L, 
8101L, 7477L, 5018L, 5063L, 11103L, 20946L, 32192L, 22665L, 29605L, 
37590L, 36692L, 16474L, 8989L, 5729L, 3909L, 8391L, 18638L, 31223L, 
40583L, 26889L, 40074L, 53218L, 52087L, 23873L, 13694L, 9354L, 
9822L), kills = c(2L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 0L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
6L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-36L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach. It can be a way to hack the plot, defining the new labels using `mutate()` and formating as factor based on the desired labels. Here the code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
#Code
new_labels <- c("cat.1","cat.2","cat.3")
#Plot
pe_ki %>%
  mutate(period=factor(period,levels = unique(period),
                       labels = new_labels,ordered = T)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(people,kills)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_grid(class~category) +
  facet_grid(rows=vars(period)) +
  stat_smooth(method="glm", method.args = list(family = "poisson"),col="black") +
  theme(strip.background = element_rect(fill="lightblue", size=1, color="darkblue"))
```

Output:

[image]

Or if the issue is only adding the suffix `cat.`:

```
#Plot 2
pe_ki %>%
  mutate(period=paste0('cat.',period)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(people,kills)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_grid(class~category) +
  facet_grid(rows=vars(period)) +
  stat_smooth(method="glm", method.args = list(family = "poisson"),col="black") +
  theme(strip.background = element_rect(fill="lightblue", size=1, color="darkblue"))
```

Output:

[image]